Unable to use Prettier as default formatter for React app in VSCode
I'm trying to install Prettier in my VScode (Windows+WSL) workspace. I succesfully installed extension and wrote this settings to my settings.json:
{
  "[typescript]": { 
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" 
  },
  "[typescriptreact]": { 
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" 
  },
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "prettier.arrowParens": "avoid",
  "prettier.enable": false,
  "prettier.printWidth": 80,
  "prettier.tabWidth": 4,
  "prettier.useTabs": false,
  "prettier.singleQuote": true,
  "prettier.trailingComma": "es5",
  "prettier.bracketSpacing": true,
}

However, when I save App.tsx file i get error in notification tab:
Extension 'Prettier - Code formatter' is configured as formatter but it cannot format 'TypeScript JSX'-files
In "Configure formatter" modal window there is no option for Prettier:
enter image description here
I already tried clean installation of VSCode 2 times (includes removing Code folder in %appdata% and all extensions) but it still doesn't seem to be working.
I expect Prettier to auto format my App.tsx file when i save.

Try use .tsx?

I'm sorry, file is already App.tsx instead of App.jsx *
